# software to record my own bank of LEGO pieces?

Tags: software, part-database

Is there any PC software that can keep track of my own pieces?

I know sites like Rebrickable and BrickLink are probably good enough, but they require VPN to access in China.

Studio can build LEGO constructions virtually, but it does not look like it can be easily used as a database for the pieces.

Comment: Rebrickable would usually be the first thing I would recommend for this, but I don't have to deal with access from China.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Brickstore](https://brickforge.de/brickstore/), it is an offline tool to install on your PC

Comment: Great!! That's very helpful!!